# Saving timestamp and IP address

Tags: php, html

When a user visits I save the IP address and the time they visited to a text file (this is protected and not publicly accessible).

The PHP is:

```html
 <?php
$file = "ipaddresses.txt";
$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$f=fopen($file, 'a+');
fwrite($f,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $timestamp."\n");
fclose($f);
?>
```

I think I've just positioned the second `timestamp` tag in the wrong place but can't seem to figure it out using `REMOTE ADDR` even though I save the time with other forms, just posting all inputs at once.

Seems a simple one but I'm lost so any help would be appreciated.

`EDIT 1:`

Please see the updated code;

```html
<?php
$file = "ipaddresses.txt";
$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$f=fopen($file, 'a+');
$info = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $timestamp . "\n";
fwrite($f, $info);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**[`fwrite()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)** only takes two arguments; the file and the information to write.

As such, you probably want to concatenate the IP and timestamp as one string:

```
fwrite($f, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $timestamp . "\n");
```

Or:

```
$info = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $timestamp . "\n";
fwrite($f, $info);
```

Comment: Please take a look at my updated code. It outputs `00.0.000.000Monday 10th of June 2019 01:52:39 AM` and there's no space between the IP and the date.

Comment: There's no space between because you haven't included a space in the data you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRealIpAddr(){
    if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])){
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $client;
    } elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $forward;
    } else{
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    return $ip;
}

$Ip_Address = getRealIpAddr();
$Timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$array = array("IP"=>$Ip_Address,"Timestamp"=>$Timestamp);
$myfile = fopen("ipaddresses.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($array));
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = "ipaddresses.txt";
$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$f=fopen($file, 'a+');
$info = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $timestamp . "\n";
fwrite($f, $info);
fclose($f);
?>
```